# How to reduce scanned ARReferenceObject file?

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

While making ARKit object detection application, the scanned object(ARReferenceObject) is 5~20MB (or more) for detecting an object smoothly.

**Is there a way to reduce this size?** Why is it needed?

I have more than 200 objects to detect. and if an object takes 5MB, then almost 1GB will be occupied only for my application, which seems not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

#### About ARReferenceObject files

High-fidelity spatial mapping's files (your reference objects), obtained from AR scanning procedure based on ARObjectScanningConfig, cannot be reduced in size. If you're aware that the size of your app will be inappropriate, then the only obvious solution is to store the `.arobject` files remotely.

A [serialized](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization) ***.arobject*** format contains a sparse point cloud (or, in other words, opaque data) which is ideally suitable for object recognition in iOS ARKit, but not for object reconstruction.

All sparse point cloud data is **large**, all dense point cloud data is **very large**.

Comment: Hi, Andy, thanks for your feedback. but I have stored the files remotely and I want to reduce file size too.

Comment: Hi @elk_cloner, The only action that will help reduce the file size is archiving. This will not significantly change the size of the files, but the processing it will definitely increase.